# Como fazer para o Eclipse mostrar o ícone do SDK e do AVD Manager?

Tags: android, android-eclipse

Tenho o JDK, SDK do Android e o Plugin do Eclipse instalado, porém quando vou na aba **window** do Eclipse não me aparece as opções do Android para configurar as AVDs e a SDK.

Como fazer para o Eclipse mostrar o ícone do SDK e do AVD Manager?

Comment: Bem vindo ao [pt.so], retirei o seu "resolvido" da pergunta pois a forma como usamos aqui para indicar que o problema está resolvido é marcando a resposta que mais nos ajudou. Como vc já a marcou está ok! Não precisa fazer mais nada. Se quiser também pode votar a favor de todas as respostas que te ajudou. Aproveite e faça um [tour] para aprender mais sobre o site. Abraço

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo esta [Resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323067/eclipse-not-showing-avd-manager-window-and-android-project),
Tente habilitar o o AVD na preferências do eclipse.
Vai em Window > Customize perspective > Command Groups Availability tab. Marque a opção "Android SDK and AVD Manager" e clique em OK.

Answer (score 1):

Seguinte, se ainda for ajudar, eu descobri aqui mexendo em tudo.

```
Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective > Action Set Availability
```

e marque a opção `Android SDK`  e `AVD`, pronto.

Answer (score 0):

Este é ícone do SDK no eclipse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso não esteja habilitado, faça isso ALGUM DESSES PASSOS:

```
Windows -> Open Perspective->Other e Selecione "Java(Default)" e clique em OK.

Window > Custom Perspective 

Command Groups Availability > Android e AVD Manager > check

Tool Bar Visibility > Android e AVD Manager > check
```

2ª Opção:Vai na pasta onde está o SDK. Lá tu inicia a aplicação sem precisar do eclipse.

Comment: Sim porem eu gostaria que a opção aparecesse no eclipse, tem como 'restaurar' essa opção?

Comment: Justamente eu queria este ícone no eclipse, mas o capiroto não deixa meu eclipse colocar ele ai...